# How to fix screen sizes for android phones?

Tags: android, xml

My app run on the my LGG4 phone correctly, screen sizes were correct. But other devices, for example working on the samsung galaxy note fan phone, screen have a lot of empty places. How can i fixed ? I changed `mpi`,`xhdpi`,... folders.
This is my `content_main xml`: (Maybe it could be that code)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="670dp">

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: create separate dimen for all device.

Comment: yes, i already have, xhdpi,mdpi,hdpi,... folders for background

Comment: no, i am saying create folder `values-sw600dp` for 7 inch tab, `values-sw720dp` for 10 inch tab, like this, inside this create file `dimens` and set dimen according to your view, make sure all file have same dimen name.

Comment: okey. i understand now thank you. i will search

Comment: According to your needs if you have to use hard-code values, then you can use this library for that  https://github.com/intuit/sdp . it has maintain many values folders for different screens.

Comment: @aj0822ArpitJoshi Excellent solution, pal!

Comment: Always welcome!